# Lose the Ajax-SliderExtender after Page Refresh (F5)

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm using a Ajax SliderExtender in a UpdatePanel. I set a BehaviorID and call `$find('behavorID').add_valueChanged` function in the $document.Ready. Everything is fine but when I press F5 and refresh the page, I lose the slider in a 1/3 (wtf) chance. If I set `var slider = $find('behavorID')`, it recognises slider is null.

I've run it in Chrome, IE8 and met the same problems.

Any ideas? solutions?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't find solution.
I used jquery slider instead.